# pass figure size in parameter

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to plot an ellipse whose size would be defined somewhere above:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\semix{0.1}
  \def\semiy{0.2}
  \draw (0,0) ellipse (\semix and \semiy);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives the following error

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `a' or `an' (in '0.1and 0.2').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8 ...\draw (\x+1,\y) ellipse (\semix and \semiy)
                                                  ;
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.


! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `a' or `an' (in '0.1and 0.2').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8 ...\draw (\x+1,\y) ellipse (\semix and \semiy)
                                                  ;
(That was another \errmessage.)
```

it seems that `\semix` consumes the space after it. However adding a backslash after it doesn't solve the problem. Actually, the number of errors rises to 11.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: You need to use `\space` (which is really just a raw space) or enclose `\semix` in braces, or better yet, use the proper notation: `\draw (x+1,\y) ellipse[x radius=\semix, y radius=\semiy];` If you set these keys in a `scope` (or a `tikzpicture`), you can just write `ellipse[]` (and might not need extra macros).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: \space doesn't help, the effect is same as when I add a backslash; Both enclosing in braces and `x radius`/`y radius` solve the problem. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Ah, it is probably not expanded early enough. I'd recommend the key syntax with the brackets anyway.